# Starting problem

Tags: initramfs

After a sudden shutdown of the pc, the computer no longer starts. The message says *initramfs* And just above are lines of text that I can't copy. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: English only site. Please translate and post the question in English.

Comment: please [edit] to include your version/distro of Ubuntu.

Comment: Take a photo of the  initramfs screen with your phone and provide a link to it in a comment.